# Share EBS storage in Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm looking at replacing a ( 2 LAMP, 2 Oracle RAC) physical configuration with an Amazon VPC.

I'm thinking of 2 Linux instances where Apache+PHP will be installed and 2 Linux instances where Oracle (or MySQL) would be installed. The Apache instance will fetch their data from the DB. I' also planning to use Amazon load-balancing from "Internet" to both LAMP.

My question is about sharing the storage between both couple.
The 2 LAMP would have the same bunch of PHP/HTML/IMG files.
The 2 DB should share their storage too.

Is there a way to attach Amazon EBS to a couple of server in the same time (regarding the server just read the data and don't try to write the same bit at the same time)?

Answer (score 2):

No, EBS devices are limited to a single instance at a time.

Why do you need two separate db's to provide a single set of data? Why not just use one db that both webservers connect to?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(

The idea was to have identical "/var/www" available from both front-end without duplicating on both instance. And setup some kind of applicative clustering on the DB size without duplicating the data either on both instance.

Comment: But why do you need one db per webserver? Is it for failover, or is it performance, or other?

Comment: it's not really 1 DB per server.
it's more 1 DB managed by 2 DB servers. so that if one DB server fails (because of a patch, a mad process or so...) the second DB server still provide access to the data.
and it would be a way to avoid both DB servers to have their own copy of the data (just because it would cost twice ;)